# Using a simple Unity 3d game in an Android Studio App

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I am new to Android Studio and have little experience with Unity. Can I import a very simple scene from Unity 3d to an existing Android Studio project and have it on one page of the app? And if so is there anything complicated about this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't there's any easy way of doing this.

Unity can create an Android project instead of building the apk.

I don't know if it supports Android Studio or Eclipe, probably Eclipse.

From there on you'll need to look into the Activity that Unity defines and add custom code to integrate it with your project. It is entirely possible to use Android native code from there on, but it's not easy.